# topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added') Not working

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm using a book called Python Crash Course to guide me. I am currently doing the app development project and I'm running into some errors. Apparently, the error is caused by this line: `topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')`. Here is my full code for views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

@login_required
def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

I checked multiple times this file and I keep getting this error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'owner' into field. Choices are: date_added, entry, id, text`. I looked at many resources with solutions but they didn't work for me. Is there a way to solve this?

Here is my Topic model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your ```Topic``` model, because it looks like your ```Topic``` model dont have ```owner``` field.

Comment: Your `Topic` model has no `owner` field...

Comment: Also consider using ```Class based views```. You would have half less code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `owner` field to the `Topic` model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...

class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

After that remember to `makemigrations` and `migrate` them :)

Comment: I have that, and still not working. My goal is to add products for a store, and the product should automatically know which store it should be added to, because the store owner shouldn't be able to choose other peoples stores.

Comment: Well, this comment does not relate on OPs question, nor my answer. How product should know which store it belongs to? While adding product to the store as a owner, you should simply filter your queryset store to see only your stores, not other owner stores.

Comment: This is how it looks **store = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all())**, how does the filter look like? This is in forms.py

Comment: We should'nt be discussing it in comments. Please create your own question with all necessary stuff, like models and form class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295425/forms-py-creating-forms-with-foreignkey-model-a-store-should-only-be-able-to-ad